# A Riley I came up with

Tags: riddle

My prefix can be found in the elements.

My infix is my suffix.

My suffix is my infix.

Who am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could be

> BANANA

because

> BA(rium) is an element, NA is suffix and infix. It is also 3 syllables long.

Comment: I was about to drop a hint, but you got it!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could be

> LADY GAGA

because

> your prefix is La+Dy (lanthanum + dysprosium) and your infix and suffix are both GA. For that matter, Ga is also an element's symbol so your infix and suffix could both be the empty string :-).

Or, if

> we want your prefix to be a single element,

you could be

> POLL or NELL, both of them perfectly reasonable names. (Prefix Po[lonium] or Ne[on], infix and suffix both L.)

Comment: It is true that it may not be unique but I'm looking for a three-syllable word

Comment: There's nothing about syllable count in the question. And it says "Who am I?" not "What am I?". (For what it's worth, the answer phenomist gave was the first thing that occurred to me but I didn't post it because I thought the question implied a person was needed.)

Comment: I wanted a generic question without giving anything away and as far as syllables are concerned I thought "Riley words" were de facto three-syllable words. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Lots of them are trisyllabic, but by no means all: e.g. solutions have included "Brexit" and "Witangemot".